# Magento 2 - How to add a custom store config in an existing tab?

Tags: magento2, core-config-data

I follow this [link](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/system-configuration/) to add a new tab in config. Is there a way to add a custom config section in an existing tab for Magento 2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, we can do this.

We should take a look:

*vendor/magento/module-payment/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="400" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Payment Methods</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Payment::payment</resource>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

The `sales` tab was defined from `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`. **So, when we want to create a new section under SALES tab, we create a new section with `<tab>sales</tab>` node.**

*app/code/Vendor1/Module1/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="custom_tab1" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="401" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Your custom tab 1</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::custom</resource>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Or if we want to add a custom field to an existing section - `custom_tab1`. Declare our custom fields inside this section.**

*app/code/Vendor2/Module2/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="custom_tab1">
        <group id="custom_group1" translate="label" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
            <label>Custom Group1</label>
            <field id="custom_field1" type="text" translate="label comment" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Custom Field 1</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

Comment: Is there a list of default options?

Comment: how to add under Customer Tab instead of under sales?

Answer (score 1):

You can create new tab under Sales Configuration Like this:

Vendor/Modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>

        <section id="orderprocessing" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Order Processing</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <resource>TrainingJaymin_OrderProcessingFee::helloworld_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Order Process Fee Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

To define its rules:

Vendor/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <helloworld>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <display_text>Hello World</display_text>
            </general>
        </helloworld>
    </default>
</config>
```

Now this will create a new tab named Order Processing Tab under Sales with having 2 fields one as a dropdown and other as a text.