# Magento 2: How to apply my jQuery click events for fields in Admin panel?

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.0. Can I apply **custom js click events** for any field in configuration page

> ***Stores -> Configuration***

This is my configuration. Here I need to load Attribute Type Dropdown based on what is chosen in Document Type dropdown.

[image]

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Reference link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139146/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-store-config-in-an-existing-tab

Answer (score 0):

Add your jquery code in below `edit.phtml` file

Don't forget to Override below file in `app/code/adminhtml/`

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-config/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml
```

Hope this solution will help you.