# How to override core shipping method system.xml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to override shipping method **system.xml** file in my module and to add a new text field there.
How to achieve this ?
thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You can see here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139150/33057